# How to create a delegate that matches the signature of a textbox-setvalue method?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, delegates

I have a wpf-application where I am using following code:

```
    //Create a Delegate that matches the Signature of the TextBox SetValue method
    private delegate void UpdateSylvacDelegate(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, Object value);

    private void Process()
    {
        var settings = new Settings();
        string value;

        //Create a new instance of our TextBox Delegate that points to the TextBox SetValue method.
        var updateTextBoxDelegate = new UpdateSylvacDelegate(textBox_Result.SetValue);
       ...
       ...
```

Now I would like to use the same code snipped in a new windows-forms application, also with a textbox (textBox_Result). For some reason there is **NO** ***SetValue*** method available for my **textBox_Result** in windows-forms when I try to create a new instance.

```
 var updateTextBoxDelegate = new UpdateSylvacDelegate(textBox_Result.???); <-- SetValue not exists here!
```

What is the reason and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Dependency properties are for WPF and Silverlight. Your question is tagged `winforms` - what kind of textbox are you actually using?

Comment: @JonSkeet a simple win-forms textBox

Comment: Right, so you don't *have* dependency properties, so you shouldn't be referring to them anywhere.

Comment: As Jon points out, the `TextBox` class you're using is from Winforms, while the `TextBox` class that has a `SetValue()` method is from WPF. You can't use the WPF class with Winforms. Based on your very sparse code example, it seems you want to be able later to set a property in the `TextBox` object in an abstract way. Depending on the exact scenario, this should be possible, but without clear detail as to how you expected to invoke the `updateTextBoxDelegate` instance, including whether this was to deal with just one property or many, it can't be answered.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask